# Mathematic notation for number of non-zero matrix entries

Tags: matrices, notation

I want to write about a matrix $M \in \{0, 1\}^{n \times m}$ and I want to use the number of non-zero entries of M. Is there a notation that I am missing here? Or should I use something like the Euclidean norm $||M||_2$ that gives the correct result but is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could set $S = \{ (i,j) \vert m_{ij} \ne 0\}$ and then use $\vert S \vert$. What do you mean with $\vert M \vert$?

Comment: No, $|M|$ has no meaning. There is the matrix norm $||M||$, but that's something else, as you said.

Comment: $\sum_{i,j} M_{ij}$ is the sum of 1's.

Comment: $|M|$ would be a bad idea, since it's often used to denote the determinant of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write $1^\top \operatorname{vec}(M)$ or $\operatorname{nnz}(M)$ to indicate the number of non-zero entries in a matrix, where $\operatorname{vec}(\cdot)$ is the vectorization operator, and nnz stands for "number of non zero".

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write something like this:

[...] where $\lvert \lvert M \rvert \rvert_2$ represents the L2 matrix norm that is equivalent to the number of non-zero entries for $M \in \{0, 1\}^{n \times m}$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).